# emacs-dired and globalff

Tags: emacs, dired

How can I pass the output of globalff to emacs-dired. Essentially I am looking for something corresponding to find-name-dired that works with output of globalff.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried it.  I have a directory named WebServiceHost, and I typed

```
M-x globalff RET webservicehost RET
```

and it displayed that directory's name -- along with all the files inside it -- in the     `*globalff*` buffer.  Happily, the directory was the selected item, so I just hit RET, and Emacs then showed me the dired buffer for that directory.

Comment: Thats not what I was looking for. I wanted all the output of globalff to be displayed in dired-mode. Essentially I have a bunch of files in directory and sub-directories that I would like it to be displayed. Find-dired turns out to be quite slow.

Comment: I suspect there's nothing like that built in; try asking on the emacs mailing list.

Answer (score -1):

I don't have a globalff answer for you. But you can do the same thing that globalff does, using **Icicles** instead. And you can open Dired on a set of files from **Icicles**.

- See http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_File-Name_Input for using **Icicles** instead of globalff. (And see http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/LocateFilesAnywhere for a comparison).
- See http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Dired_Enhancements#OpenDiredOnSavedFiles for opening Dired on a set of files that match your minibuffer input in **Icicles**.

Comment: Whoever: Care to explain why you downvoted this answer?